# Problem with updating compose version to 1.3.0-alpha01

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have an Android Studio project that works fine when I'm using Kotlin version `1.6.21` and compose version `1.2.0-rc01`. The problem arises when I want to update both dependencies to the latest versions, which are [`1.7.10`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html) for Kotlin and [`1.3.0-alpha01`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui) for compose. The error that I get is:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension'.
> Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.3.0-alpha01.
> Searched in the following locations:
>
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/1.3.0-alpha01/compiler-1.3.0-alpha01.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/1.3.0-alpha01/compiler-1.3.0-alpha01.pom

> Required by:
> project :app

Any help?

Edit:

Now I'm using these versions:

```
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.7.10'

implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.3.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.2.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate Compose compiler version can be defined with `composeOptions`:

```
android {
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.2.0"
    }
}
```

There's no need to add it as an `implementation`, which it definitely isn't.
`runtimeOnly` might eventually work, but it won't make it into the package.

Comment: Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: You also need to set kotlin to 1.7.0. There is currently no KT 1.7.10 support in Compose

Answer (score 5):

Compose compiler and the other compose dependencies have **different releases**.
Currently the latest version of [compose.compiler](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler#1.2.0) is **`1.3.1`**.

You easily use different versions in your `build.gradle` script:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_compiler = '1.3.1'.     //compiler
        compose_version = '1.2.0'.      //stable compose dependencies
        compose_alpha = '1.3.0-alpha01' //alpha releases
    }
    //...
}
```

And then:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_compiler
}

dependencies {
   //stable releases
   implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"

   //alpha releases
   implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_alpha"
   implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:$compose_alpha"
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for getting the time to answer my question. If I use the latest versions (1.7.10 for Kotlin and 1.3.0-alpha01 for compose), and also add `implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.2.0"`, I'm still getting the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: @JoanP. The same error for the compiler or for other modules? Keep attention because currently not all modules are available at 1.3.0-alpha01.

Comment: Please check my edited question with my latest dependencies, and I get the exact same error. Do you know why? Voted-up, btw.

Comment: The kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0-rc02' need Kotlin version '1.6.21'. And so I changed Kotlin version  to '1.6.21'  from '1.7.10' . After that I found '1.3.0-alpha01' is effecting to all my compose dependeyncies and the build succeeding.

Answer (score 2):

There is a compatibility map for "***Compose Compiler Version***" compatible with "***Compatible Kotlin Version***" it can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin#pre-release_kotlin_compatibility):

so if you want to update to today's latest compose you specify:

```
...
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.3.0"
}
...
```

and then in the map you find the compatible kotlin version which is 1.7.10
and set that in the other gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, David. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using **compose_version** is **1.3.0-beta01** which is working fine for me. You may use like below:

**Step1**: **Project build.gadle** is look like below:

```
   build script {

        ext {
            compose_version =  '1.3.0-beta01'
        }
     }

   plugins {
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
       
    }
```

**Step2**: module build.gadle looks like

```
  composeOptions {

    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.21'

 }
```